# Python: No pip file

Tags: python, macos, pip

**Mac OS**: when I try to run anything involving pip, I get

```
-bash: pip: command not found
```

This happened after I accidentally deleted the pip Unix file in `usr/local/bin` while trying to solve a different problem with pip. At this point, I've pretty much given up on solving the problem manually.

> Is there a way to just completely uninstall python and pip and start all over again?

Comment: Did you originally install python and pip with brew? If so you should be able to uninstall and reinstall.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/324980/how-do-you-re-install-a-package-with-homebrew-mac This might be helpful

Comment: I already tried "brew reinstall" but it didn't bring the file back

Answer (score 1):

In recent python versions pip is as module rather than as individual script. Try:

```
python -m pip
```

Comment: I get "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: No module named pip"

Comment: "*In recent python versions pip is as module rather than as individual script.*" It always was both a package and a script to import function `main` from the package and call it.

Comment: @steinchen This is a very old python version. I checked on my system (apparently very simliar) and indeed it does not include pip. I would recommend to install a recent version of python, preferably 3.7. It does not interfer with the system python.

Answer (score 0):

solution was surprisingly simple: deleted everything python related from my computer:

1. deleted `Python` App in `Applications` Folder
2. deleted all python and pip related files in `usr/local/bin`
3. deleted the `Python.framework` folder in `Libraray/Frameworks`
4. searched for and deleted all folders named `python`

Then I reinstalled Python via the official python page. Pip seems to work now.